# Adding links to an array with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I am trying to loop through all of the links on a page and add them to an array using jquery but I can't seem to get it quite right.

What I have is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var links = new Array();
var link;

for (link in $("a"))
{
links.push(link);
}

alert(links);

});
```

What I get is an array of numbers (I think one for each link on the page), and properties, events, etc. like 'selector', 'context', ... 'onmouseover' and so on.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `$('a')` you already have a jQuery object, which is an array-like object.

If you want an actual `Array` of elements, you can convert it to an `Array` with `$.makeArray()`.

```
var array = $.makeArray( $('a') );
```

- http://api.jquery.com/jquery.makearray/

---

**EDIT:** If you're curious about why you were getting those unexpected results in the `for/in`, fire up the developer tools in your favorite browser, and log a jQuery object to the console. You'll see all those (prototyped) properties you were getting.

```
console.log( $('a') );
```