# Storing an Array in localStorage Using JSON.stringify

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, local-storage

I [just learned about jquery's .makeArray](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340027/adding-links-to-an-array-with-jquery) and I am trying to use JSON.stringify to store the array in localStorage but I am having unexpected results.

This works:

```
var links = {'one': 1, 'two': 2 };
var setstr = JSON.stringify(links);

localStorage.setItem('strlinks', setstr);
var getstr = localStorage.getItem('strlinks');
console.log(getstr); //Returns what's expected - '{"one":1, "two":2}'
```

This doesn't:

```
var links = $.makeArray($('a'));

alert(links); //Returns list of links
var setstr = JSON.stringify(links);

localStorage.setItem('strlinks', setstr);
var getstr = localStorage.getItem('strlinks');
console.log(getstr); //Returns '[]'
```

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`links` contains circular references, so it can't be serialized to JSON.  Chrome 5.0.375.99 gives the error:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

You have to somehow remove these circular references.  Of course, it depends what info you care about.  Here's a simplified version:

```
var flatLinks = $.map(links, function(el)
                             {
                              return {href: el.href, text: el.textContent};
                             }); 
var setstr = JSON.stringify(flatLinks);
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('a')` selects all the links (`HTMLAnchorElement`s) on the page.

Elements are DOM nodes defined by their identity and presence in the document. They are not simple values that JSON can represent. If you look at what `JSON.stringify()` returns for them, it's just `{}`: JSON says all it knows about the object is that it's an `Object`.

It doesn't make any sense to attempt to put a Node inside a `localStorage`; what do you expect to get back when you read the storage tomorrow? A Node object that was part of a document the user closed and destroyed yesterday?

If you want to remember where the links pointed to, you should get that from their `href` properties, as a `String`—a simple value type that can safely be remembered by `localStorage`.

Comment: Maybe I am barking up the wrong tree but this is for a chrome extension.  My thought was to add the array to localStorage from a content script, then when the user clicks the browser icon, loop through the links and display them in a popup.  I am new to chrome extensions, but it is my understanding that a popup can't directly access the variables from a content script, thus the need for local storage.  But I could be way off the mark.

Comment: A reference to a link cannot be put in a `String`, the only thing `localStorage` will store. But the popup doesn't need to touch the link itself, does it? It only needs to know the URL that the link is pointing to (`href`), surely? That's only a `String`, so can certainly be JSON-stringified. Not that I think you actually need `localStorage` at all. I don't know about Chrome, but most browser extensions should have no trouble opening a new window and populating it with a list of strings, without having to mediate through any kind of `localStorage` database.

Comment: You can use a background page as a controller, and access the stored values from there.  See my New Tab Redirect's code for examples (I am using JSON.stringify in trunk's code) http://code.google.com/p/newtabredirect/